# How to prevent reverse engineering apk to get server login?

Tags: android, security, obfuscation

I'm trying to find a way to make my Android app secure before releasing it.  Currently I'm using https/ssl for server communication, with hidden password protected directories on the server that the app talks to.  In those directories the app interfaces with PHP scripts that handle communication with the server data. My biggest vulnerability as I see it is the use of literal strings in the apk file to get access to the server password protected directories where the PHP scripts are. These literal strings could be detected by binary inspection or possibly attaching a debugger. What I've read so far is that it's not possible to obfuscate a literal string.

My question is, how can I prevent the discovery of the passwords to the hidden directories where the operating PHP scripts are? Alternately, what other approach should I be taking to keep server logins secure and reduce the chance of server attacks?

Comment: Have you considered encryption? and keeping the private key on the server?

Comment: That's an interesting idea too. I've read about encryption and it's limitations, but didn't see the obvious and useful solution of keeping the key only on the server.  Just need to keep the key location from getting discovered. Thanks.

Comment: You simply **can't prevent** reverse engineering. You can only **make it harder**.

Comment: That's what I've been reading also, but I want to get up to speed on the best practices. Two good ideas have been presented here.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach is to verify your app's signing certificate at run time. From that you don't need to hard-code any credentials in the app. currently Facebook SDK is using it. Please look at following.

- https://www.airpair.com/android/posts/adding-tampering-detection-to-your-android-app
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: This is good information. I will start working on that. I wonder too, could the app's certificate be sent to the server as a password as well?  That way if the string literals are hacked and used to directly attack the server outside the app, the certificate would be wrong/missing and the PHP script would block access...?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would make more sense to use encryption than to leave it unencrypted, you'd need to control how you deal with the Private key.

Comment: I suppose it would be possible to encrypt the server directory location as well, and decrypt it on the fly from within the app, perhaps using the apk certificate as the key. SSL should hide the location from network probes. The combination would help prevent discovery of the server location.